# Get all invoices in Magento

Tags: magento, invoice

How do I get all the invoices collection?

I know that to get all the orders is:

```
 $orders = Mage::getModel(sales/order)->getCollection();
```

However I can't seem to find the equivalent with invoice (it's not sales/invoice). Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use :

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();
```

For the explanation :

When you want to access i block/model/resource/helper/etc in magento :

- first, you choose the right method to access it : `Mage::getModel` for a model
- second, you must tell magento "which" module you want to access. You do that with the first part of the parameter string :

> Mage::getModel("**sales**/order_invoice")

This string refers to the XML node of the type or resource you want to access. In your case, for accessing a model of the Mage_Sales module : take a look at the Mage_Sales's config.xml, you'll see the node to use (used for models and resourceModels) :

```
[...]
<models>
    <sales><!-- <----- THIS NODE -->
        <class>Mage_Sales_Model</class>
         <resourceModel>sales_resource</resourceModel>
     </sales>
     [...]
```

- last part, you need to add the full access to the file you want, with folder if needed. In your case, in the Model folder of the Mage_Sales module (above xml config tells us that this folder is `Mage_Sales_Model`), you'll see a file `Invoice.php` in the `Order` folder : then you path is "order_invoice" and the full commande to access your model is :

> Mage::getModel("sales/**order_invoice**")

Comment: I don't understand much about accessing the model structure in Magento. Thanks anyway

Comment: How we can get invoice based on current order object in magento 2?