# magento how to call custom model

Tags: magento, model, module

How can I call model in a custom module? Lets assume that model is really simple one and returns just arrays of static data.

I have a directory structure similar to this:

- app

  - local

    - Mypackage

      - Module

        - Models

          - Model1.php

How can I include Model1.php inside controller? If I go with **Mage::getModel('Mypackage/Modul/Model1)** it returns error since it searches model inside Mage/Module/Model/Model1.php

Thanks!

Comment: you have to call this way `Mage::getModel('Module/Model1)`.

Comment: @Pankaj, but since its a custom package this is not working :(

Comment: @Bixi can you provide a link where this is explained?

Comment: @Miha Trtnik : see my answer on other thread : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13203197/1112003

Comment: @bixi thanks, I was missing xml config

another good tutorial I've found after pointed in right direction is here http://codemagento.com/2011/02/creating-and-instantiating-a-model/

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getModel('modulename/modelname')->modelmethod();

i.e.
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getName();
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::getModel('mypackage_module/modeltest)` should work. But first check your config.xml. 
You should have declared it like so:

```
          <models>
            <mypackage_module>
                <class>Mypackage_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>modeltest_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mypackage_module>
            <modeltest_mysql4>
                <class>Mypackage_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <modeltest>
                        <table>mypackage_module</table>
                    </modeltest>
                </entities>
            </modeltest_mysql4>
          </models>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this but I have not tested it

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('Module/Model1')->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
Mage::getModel('module/model_model1')->modelmethod();

Please note that the model folder should be "Model" not "Models"