# Why Magento return wrong class in the .phtml file?

Tags: magento

I have 3d-party extention that add new tabs while product edit at the backend. Now I want to add one more tab there.

New tab should have "add" button and let user to add new item, In addition It should have the list with added items. First of all, I have looked at extention code. They have added similar tab using

```
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
```

So I try to folow their way and add my one. Code below.

```
    $this->addTab('cancellpolicy', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Cancellation Policies'),
            'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy')->toHtml()),
        ));
```

Above I add new tab and then I create new block class below

```
class Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy 

extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface 
{

   /**
 * Form element instance
 *
 * @var Varien_Data_Form_Element
 */
protected $_element;

/**
 * Customer Groups cache
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_customerGroups;

/**
 * Websites cache
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_websites;



public function __construct(){
    $this->setTemplate('reservation/product/edit/tab/cancellationpolicy.phtml');
}

 public function getProduct(){
    return Mage::registry('product');
}
public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element){
    $this->setElement($element);
    return $this->toHtml();
}


protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild('add_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Add Room Type(s)'),
                'onclick'   => 'roomtypesControl.addItem()',
                'class' => 'add'
            )));   

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}


 /**
 * Set form element instance
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
 * @return Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy
 */   
public function setElement(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element){
    $this->_element = $element;
    return $this;
}



/**
 * Retrieve form element instance
 *
 * @return Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy
 */
public function getElement(){
    return $this->_element;
}    


public function getWebsites()
{

    if (!is_null($this->_websites)) {
        return $this->_websites;
    }
    $websites = array();
    $websites[0] = array(
        'name'      => $this->__('All Websites'),
        'currency'  => Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode()
    );
    if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode() || $this->getElement()->getEntityAttribute()->isScopeGlobal()) {
        return $websites;
    }
    elseif ($storeId = $this->getProduct()->getStoreId()) {
        $website = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsite();
        $websites[$website->getId()] = array(
            'name'      => $website->getName(),
            'currency'  => $website->getConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE),
        );
    }
    else {
        $websites[0] = array(
            'name'      => $this->__('All Websites'),
            'currency'  => Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode()
        );
        foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
            if (!in_array($website->getId(), $this->getProduct()->getWebsiteIds())) {
                continue;
            }
            $websites[$website->getId()] = array(
                'name'      => $website->getName(),
                'currency'  => $website->getConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE),
            );
        }
    }
    $this->_websites = $websites;
    return $this->_websites;
}

public function getValues(){
    return Mage::getModel('reservation/roomtypes')->getCollection()
                ->addEntityIdFilter($this->getProduct()->getId())
                ->addStoreIdFilter($this->getProduct()->getStoreId())
                ->getItems();
}

}
```

And then add reservation/product/edit/tab/cancellationpolicy.phtml template file. A the beginig of template I get

```
<?php   Mage::log(get_class($this->getElement())); ?>
<?php $_htmlId      = $this->getElement()->getHtmlId() ?>
<?php $_htmlClass   = $this->getElement()->getClass() ?>
<?php $_storeId     = $this->getProduct()->getStoreId() ?>
<?php $_htmlName    = $this->getElement()->getName() ?>
<?php $_readonly    = $this->getElement()->getReadonly() ?>
<?php $_multiWebsite= 0 && !Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode() ?>
```

And here I get error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getHtmlId() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/bluning.com/httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/reservation/product/edit/tab/cancellationpolicy.phtml on line 10

```
Mage::log(get_class($this->getElement()));
```

give me "Mage_Core_Block_Template" but why? As per my code getElement() should return "Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy"

So why Magento return wrong class in the .phtml file?

**UPDATE**
config.xml has section

```
      <blocks>
        <reservation>
            <class>Apptha_Reservation_Block</class>
        </reservation>

    </blocks>
```

**UPDATE2**
I have placed Mage::log inside getElement function and after calling. It returns different values:

```
inside: Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy
outside: Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

Crazy

Comment: What is the type of $this? Try get_class($this) - maybe your block class is not applied properly. What I do not unterstand is that get_class returns a class, but then it complains that getElement() is not an object. Try to use the debugger to narrow things down.

Comment: get_class($this) return "Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy" It's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using debugger I have found issue.

```
$this->getElement()
```

It return NULL because It hasnt been set properly. It should be set in the observer. Code is below:

```
  public function attachPolicyEditor($observer) {
    $form = $observer->getForm();
    if ($policies = $form->getElement('apptha_hotel_cancellationpolicy')) {
        $policies->setRenderer(
            Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('reservation/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_cancellationpolicy')
        );
    }
}
```

attachPolicyEditor is called by adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form observer.

Answer (score 0):

The line :

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Apptha_Reservation_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Cancellationpolicy')
```

is totally invalid. You need to respect the magento framework syntax. (it'ns not just a class instantiation)

See my answer here for details on how to access resoruces in magento : [Get all invoices in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203128/get-all-invoices-in-magento/13203197#13203197)

To get it work you need to call it via :

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('apptha_reservation/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_cancellationpolicy')
```

ps: if "apptha_reservation" is your declared block XML tag in your config.xml

Comment: Now It returns "Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/bluning.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Apptha/Reservation/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php on line 83"

I have updated my question

Comment: check my linked post, check your config.xml file, check your paths, check everything.

Comment: It works with "reservation/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_cancellationpolicy" but then It displays originally error (like im my question)

Comment: your config.xml block's XML tag <reservation> should be different (your using magento default one's without really rewriting it). Change it to : <apptha_reservation> and use $this->getLayout()->createBlock('apptha_reservation/[...]

Comment: No, because if I delete "implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface" from block then It's working fine. But my block should have  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface behaviour.